# Automatically save Facebook photos where I have been tagged

Tags: facebook, automation, facebook-photos

I would like to automatically capture any photos post on Facebook in which I am tagged. For instance, a friend posts some photos from a get-together and I'm tagged in some. I'd like to be able to grab them before something bad happens (like the poster realizes that maybe some of them shouldn't have been made public).

Ideally I would get these photos in one of the cloud accounts I have, but any method of getting the image files would suffice (like email).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A webapp like [IFTTT - If This Than That](https://ifttt.com/recipes/289152-save-a-copy-of-the-picture-to-dropbox-if-i-m-tagged-on-it) is probably the easiest way to achieve this.

[Sign up on IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/join), use [this recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/289152-save-a-copy-of-the-picture-to-dropbox-if-i-m-tagged-on-it) that I have published & click on Add recipe button (if required, you'll be prompted to activate the necessary channels) to automatically store a copy of the pic to Dropbox.

If you prefer, you can have the picture sent to you via email or via [other options](https://ifttt.com/channels) - you'll need to search/create a recipe of your own.

Caveat: Because of the way IFTTT works, it might take couple of minutes for it to be added to Dropbox, but it [definitely does work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdm2S.png).

Comment: I use [this recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/75659-save-all-facebook-photo-s-i-m-tagged-in-to-google-drive) (I have more space at Google Drive) but it's exactly what I was looking for.